# How to define a custom schema to read csv file?

Tags: csv, pyspark, schema

I´m trying to define a custom schema without all the columns from the csv file, is this possible?

When i try to do it, the values are not corresponding to the columns i specified, because it keeps printing the order from the csv file.

DataSet: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/dataset/GreenThumb-Garden-Info/p78i-pat6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHFT.png

Comment: in contrast to other formats, like, JSON, data from CSV by definition are dependent on the order of the columns... So you need to define at least all columns up to the last you need + 1 (as catch all)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on the link to sample data you have provided, I've added a full schema, that should allow you to read in the sample CSV data without any problems. If you don't need some of the fields, you can just use `select` and choose only these that are relevant to your further processing needs. Sample schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

customSchema = StructType([
  StructField("assemblydist", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("borough", StringType(), True),
  StructField("communityboard", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("congressionaldist", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("coundist", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("gardenname", StringType(), True),
  StructField("juris", StringType(), True),
  StructField("multipolygon", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrsf", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrsm", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrssa", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrssu", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrsth", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrstu", StringType(), True),
  StructField("openhrsw", StringType(), True),
  StructField("parksid", StringType(), True),
  StructField("policeprecinct", StringType(), True),
  StructField("statesenatedist", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("status", StringType(), True),
  StructField("zipcode", IntegerType(), True)
])
```

If you want to decode the `Multi-Polygon` type, then this will require extra step of parsing that data - for ease of use I've just read it as a plain string.